# Get data attributes on click for each and output ICS

Tags: javascript, jquery, icalendar

I have some code that works from a codepen found here https://codepen.io/daviddarnes/pen/Oomper

What i am trying to do is for each a link that is an add to celendar get the data attributes and dynamically add them to the event.

My links would look like this

```
<a href="#client-cal" class="new-cal-event"
            data-title="Event 1"
            data-start="11/16/2021 5:45 AM"
            data-end="11/16/2021 6:30 AM"
            data-location="Some Location 4"
            data-description="This is the desctiption">
      Event 1 Add to Calendar</a>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a href="#client-cal" class="new-cal-event"
            data-title="Event 2"
            data-start="11/17/2021 9:45 AM"
            data-end="11/16/2021 10:30 AM"
            data-location="Some Location 2"
            data-description="This is the desctiption">
      Event 2 Add to Calendar</a>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a href="#client-cal" class="new-cal-event"
            data-title="Event 3"
            data-start="11/17/2021 11:45 AM"
            data-end="11/16/2021 12:30 PM"
            data-location="Some Location 3"
            data-description="This is the desctiption">
      Event 3 Add to Calendar</a>
      <br>
      <br>
```

Then I have the following jsfiddle with the javascript but am unable to get it to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/6ow8nbz7/30/

**It needs to work on click and build the ical url string and not on page load.**

```
// Based on https://github.com/contra/generate-calendar-url

const formatTime = (date, allDay) => {
  if (allDay) {
    return date.toISOString().replace(/-|:|\.\d+/g, "").split('T')[0];
  }
  return date.toISOString().replace(/-|:|\.\d+/g, "");
};

const google = ({
  title = "",
  start = "",
  end = "",
  allDay = false,
  description = "",
  location = "",
  url = ""
}) => {
  const data = {
    action: "TEMPLATE",
    text: title,
    dates: `${formatTime(start, allDay)}/${formatTime(end, allDay)}`,
    details: description + "%0A" + url,
    location: location
  };

  return `https://www.google.com/calendar/render?${Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => key + "=" + data[key])
    .join("&")}`;
};

const ics = ({
  title = "",
  start = "",
  end = "",
  allDay = false,
  description = "",
  location = "",
  url = ""
}) => {
  return encodeURI(
    "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," +
      [
        `BEGIN:VCALENDAR`,
        `VERSION:2.0`,
        `BEGIN:VEVENT`,
        `URL:${url}`,
        `DTSTART:${formatTime(start, allDay)}`,
        `DTEND:${formatTime(end, allDay)}`,
        `SUMMARY:${title}`,
        `DESCRIPTION:${description}`,
        `LOCATION:${location}`,
        `END:VEVENT`,
        `END:VCALENDAR`
      ].join("\n")
  );
};

const cal = {
  google: google,
  client: ics
};

var dataTitle = element.getAttribute("data-title");
var dataStart = element.getAttribute("data-start");
var dataEnd = element.getAttribute("data-end");
var dataLocation = element.getAttribute("data-location");
var dataDescription = element.getAttribute("data-description");

// title, start, and end are required
const event = {
  title: element.getAttribute("data-title"),
  start: element.getAttribute("data-start"),
  end: element.getAttribute("data-end"),
  allDay: false,
  location: element.getAttribute("data-location"),
  description: element.getAttribute("data-description"),
  url: this.url
};
document.querySelector("[href='#client-cal']").href = cal.client(event);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not see where you assign a callback to the `click` event.

Comment: I tried to assign it but clearly do not know what i am doing as i am just getting errors in the consol. Frustrating.